# How can I pause the game when a window pops up in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, popup

My game pops up a window for rating the game after every 10 times the game ends.
And its random that when will it appear.
So I just want to pause  the game whenever the window appears.
How can I call the pause exactly on the time when window appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your window is ingame(GUI) then to stop all ingame activities you may set Time.timeScale to 0 then reset to 1 after window closing. See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html

But if your window is external to application (JS) you may just set Application.runInBackground = false. See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-runInBackground.html

Answer (score 0):

[How do I pause my game?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7544/how-do-i-pause-my-game.html)

[How to pause and resume the game?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/630303/how-to-pause-and-resume-the-game.html)

Before posting question At least search yourself in related Forum and in Google. I don't think this is not too much difficult to find it out...